# How do I change the icon of an app bar button toggle in c# code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to change the icon of an app bar button toggle once it is checked then again when it is unchecked. I am sure the .icon property is used but I don't know what to set it to. I want to change it from a play to a pause button each time it is clicked.

```
    private void abtnTimer_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
               AppBarToggleButton btn = sender as AppBarToggleButton;
                if (btn.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    btn.Icon = //not sure what this should be
                    string s = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                    localSettings.Values["Timer"] = s;
                }
                else
                {
                    btn.Icon = //turn the icon into a play icon
                    DateTime dte = Convert.ToDateTime(localSettings.Values["Timer"]);
                    TimeSpan t;
                    t = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dte);
                    txtblkHoursData.Text = t.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it to SymbolIcon - Play for play symbol:

```
btn.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Play);
```

and Pause for pause symbol:

```
btn.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Pause);
```